# Слиянием двух массивов в один

Tags: массивы, c

Даны два убывающих массива. Необходимо их слить в один убывающий массив.Вот код программы.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

   int main() {

       int N, M, a[100], b[100], c[100], i, j, k;

       scanf("%d", &N);/*ввод массивов*/

       for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
           scanf("%d", &a[i]);
       }

       scanf("%d", &M);

       for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
           scanf("%d", &b[i]);
       }
    for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; k < N + M; k++) {
       if (i == N) {
          c[k] = b[j];/*если массив a исчерпан, берём элементы из массива b*/
          j++;
          continue;
      }

      if (j == M) {
         c[k] = a[i];/*если массив b исчерпан, то берём элементы из массива a*/
         i++;
         continue;
      }

                    if (a[i] > b[i]) {/*если ни один из массивов не исчерпан, то выбираем наименьший*/
                       c[k] = a[i];
                       i++;
                       k++;
                       c[k] = b[j];
                       j++;
                    }

                    else {
                       c[k] = b[j++];
                       c[k++] = a[i++];
                    }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N + M; i++) {
       printf("%d\n", c[i]);
    }

    getch();

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: И что Вы хотите от нас?

Comment: о, лабы пошли. в октябре рановато :)

Comment: Прошу помочь разобраться. В чём ошибка?

Comment: @MahovIV, а что Вас не устраивает? 

Другими словами: *в чем проявляется ошибка?* 

--

Неужели Вы серьезно считаете, что тут куча желающих взять любой код, изучить его, восстановить постановку задачи, откомпилировать, погонять на разных наборах тестовых данных, а потом выложить Вам подробный отчет и рекомендации по необходимым (а также желаемым, например, с т.з. эстетики) изменениях в коде?

--

Для начала напишите, что **точно делали**, что **конкретно увидели** на экране и объясните, чем это **отличается** от того, что Вы **ожидали увидеть**.

Comment: @MahovIV, уточните в чем проблема (выскакивает ошибка, зависает, война, эпидемия, снежный буран?..) Без этого с вероятностью 90% никто не будет вчитываться в код.

У меня есть несколько замечаний:

1. При вводе, как вы определяете, когда закончился ввод первого массива и начинается ввод второго? неужели сами считаете?
2. `c[k++] = a[i++];` вы на 100% уверены, что операции выполнятся в нужном порядке? Я вот просто не в курсе, потому что не нужно.

Comment: @insolor, с порядком операций в выражении `c[k++] = a[i++];` все в порядке.

Не в порядке с KISS принципом. Все переменные смешаны в кучу. Ведь очевидно же, что общая часть алгоритма слияния выражается 

    while (array1_curpos < array1_len && array2_curpos < array2_len)
      if (array1[array1_curpos] > array2[array2_curpos])
        result[res_curpos++] = array1[array1_curpos++];
      else
        result[res_curpos++] = array2[array2_curpos++];

вот таким циклом. Далее в `result` переписывается хвост одного из массивов.

Просто разбираться, что конкретно не работает в логике автора лень.

Answer (score 1):

Я Си не знаю,<br>
но первое, что бросается в глаза - это размеры массивов. Когда известны размеры(а по всей видимости размеры даны изначально) тут скорее намек не использовать ни quick sort и ни merge sort.

Размер третьего массива должен составлять оба массива в сумме - это раз.

Два - можно пробежаться одним незамысловатым циклом с двумя указателями и парой простых условий + проверка на определение большего значения и таким образом по порядку забить третий массив.

Таким образом можно решить задачу с Time complexity: O(n);

Comment: @qpaycm,

> можно пробежаться одним незамысловатым циклом с двумя указателями и парой простых условий + проверка на определение большего значения и таким образом по порядку забить третий массив.

По задумке автора программа это и делает.

Comment: @insolor, никак телепат вернулся из отпуска? ;-)

Comment: @qpaycm, никакой мистики, просто знаю си. Даже если не знать его: сортировка - это как минимум два вложенных цикла. У автора один цикл и три условия в нем.